# Change classes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want on first click to add class `up`, on second click to add class `down`, and on third click to remove all classes.

This is my code, but classes are not applying in respective order:

```
function initAdClass() {
    var trigger =   '.post-info h2';
    jQuery(trigger).click(function(e) { 
        if ( jQuery(this).not('.up') && jQuery(this).not('.down') ) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('up');
        }
        else if ( jQuery(this).is('.up') && jQuery(this).not('.down') ) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('up').addClass('down');
        }
        else if ( jQuery(this).not('.up') && jQuery(this).is('.down') ) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('down');
        }           
    });
}
```

Comment: try change `not` to `hasClass`

Comment: @Shahnawa Khalid did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet.

```js
var clicks=0;
$('a').click(function(){
  
  clicks = !isNaN($(this).attr('id')) ? $(this).attr('id') + 1 : 0; 
  if(clicks == 1)
  {
    $(this).addClass('Up').html('Up added');  
  } 
  if(clicks == 2)
  {
    $(this).removeClass('Up').addClass('Down').html('Up removed and Down Added');  
  } 
  if(clicks == 3)
  {
    $(this).removeClass().html('All removed');
    clicks=0;
  }
  $(this).attr('id', clicks);
  $(this).append(" " + clicks);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Trigger : 1 : </a>

<br/><br/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)">Trigger : 2 : </a>

<br/><br/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)">Trigger : 3 : </a>
```

Comment: it is working fine, but there is a bug, if we have 2 or more then 2 triggers in a row, then need to remove the class from other trigger and add class on "this" trigger, and "clicks" should be count according to clicked trigger.

currently the counting of clicks are based on generic trigger, add 2 more triggers then you will see the counting error.

Comment: @ShahnawazKhalid Show me your HTML, what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ShahnawazKhalid I've edited my answer, Is this what you're looking for ?